# C++ For Loop Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, for-loop, visual-c++

I am attempting to create nested for loops to output the grid below for homework.  Here are my progress and instructions (this really should be simple...):

"Create an 8x8 grid like the one below. Tab in to start each row. Each cell is one row tall and three spaces wide. Dash (-) characters (33) were used to construct the horizontal lines."

[image]

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{


    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout<<"I\t";
    }

    for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }

    cout<<"\n";
}


cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

my output:

[image]

Comment: So what are your questions?

Comment: I will post the terminal output.

Comment: You can use iomanip with setw for the columns. -Or- you can construct string objects that contain the string for each row, ie string('-', NUM_OF_DASHES).

Comment: Don't you need a `endl` after each of the 2 inner loops?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but it doesn't look a million miles away. What specific issue is it that you're not understanding?

Comment: Please see my output picture.

Comment: OK, well the problem is that you don't have a newline between the I I I I and the -----. Surely that's an easy problem to fix.

Comment: First, you should switch the loops. The dashes appear before. Then do the loop again for the last row. Second, the other commenter is right about the endl's.

Comment: in c++, you typically use `endl` not `"\n"`. and as Luchian pointed out, you've missed one between your loops. Also a tab character is (usually) 8 characters, not 3. Just use spaces instead.

Comment: Switching the loop isn't necessary. There's one more line of dashes than vertical bars. So you either going to have to output one line of dashes before or after your main loop.

Comment: Thank you John and Dave.  John is first though.  I need to mark you down as the answer somehow.

Comment: @Dave I typically use '\n' not endl, endl has a specific meaning (newline following by flush) which doesn't seem important here.

Comment: http://ideone.com/WtrDzZ

Comment: @john I wasn't aware of that. In that case yes, use `"\n"` until the very last call (although I believe most unix systems flush automatically when the string ends in a newline, and maybe windows too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{


    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout<<"I\t";
    }

    cout << endl;

    for(int k=0;k<57;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }

    cout<<"\n";
}


cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yours was most like mine, I had to accept it.  Everyone else was most helpful.

Comment: Maybe it is like yours but I don't think it's exactly what is wanted from you as you described the problem.

Comment: I wasn't sure what he wanted exactly. I just corrected the formatting a little bit without changing the code too much.

Answer (score 2):

It must be something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        cout << "\t";
        for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
        {
            cout<<"-";
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << "\t";
        for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
            cout<<"I   ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << "\t";
    for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

[image: This]

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i=0;i<8;i++)      
   {                
       for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
         {
                cout<<"I\t";


            for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
            {
                cout<<"-";
            }

            cout<<"\n";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout<<"\t";
for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
    cout<<"\t";
    for(int j=0; j<9; j++)
    {
        cout<<"I   ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout<<"\t";
    for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }

    cout << endl;
    }


cin.get();


return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
{


    for(int j=0; j<8; j++)
    {
        cout<<"I   ";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int k=0;k<33;k++)
    {
        cout<<"-";
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}


cin.get();
cin.get();

return 0;
}
```

[image]